# A Verb Meaning be Positioned at

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I want a verb meaning "be positioned at" for the following sentence. What can I use?

In each list, no positive item can ... before an irrelevant one.

I used take place, but it seems that it's meaning is different in English.

Comment: _Be positioned at_ is a verb phrase; so is _be located at_. There isn't a single, inflectable verb with that meaning.

Answer (score 3):

*Place* is not used intransitively, except in speaking of competitions; but passive *be placed* will work just dandy; it's essentially the same as *be positioned*, but a little more everyday.

*Lie* and *appear* are common intransitives in contexts like this

> No positive item can *appear* before an irrelevant one.
>   No positive item can *lie* before an irrelevant one.

Comment: Does lie make sense in a mathematical context and in talking about lists and buckets of numbers? Moreover, there are several other answers. Do you think which one is best suited?

Comment: Another common intransitive is ***occur***, which in OP's exact context is probably a lot more common than ***lie*** (though in some other contexts I'm sure ***lie, sit*** actually work better than ***appear, occur***).

Comment: What does OP stand for?

Comment: @Shayan “Original Post[er]”, that is, you. Another very simple option for your particular case: ***come***.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Or ***go***.

Answer (score 3):

In the particular context given in the question, that is:

> In each list, no positive item can ... before an irrelevant one.

I believe the word "**occur**" can fill in that blank.  This verb (like "appear", which I noticed StoneyB suggests) uses the active voice; most other alternatives in common use will use the passive voice, as suggested by the other answers so far.

Answer (score 1):

***Be placed:***

[Place](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/placed):

> - To put in or as if in a particular place or position; set.

..no positive item can *be placed* before an irrelevant one.

Answer (score 0):

### Situated

> In each list, no positive item can **be situated** before an irrelevant one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a descending value of things, I'd suggest **ordered**.